# Windows Server: The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found

Tags: .net-core, windows-server

I am trying to run a dotnet core api (2.1.0) on my Windows Server (2012 R2) by running the following command: `dotnet Api.dll` But I keep getting the following message.

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

The api runs normally on my mac, when I use the same command (`dotnet Api.dll`). When I use `dotnet --info` I get the following and it says the latest Runtime and SDK are installed.

```
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.3.9600
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win81-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.
App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.
App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.
App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Already tried adding the `PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest` part and re-publish. It did gave me more files when publishing but didn't work for my current issue.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
->  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest> <-
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0" />
    ....
```

Could it be because its looking for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and I got `Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0` installed? I don't know really, I know the latest .NET core runtime and sdk are installed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could it be because its looking for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and I got
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 installed?

Yes, you are correct. You have the appropriate `Microsoft.NETCore.App` runtimes installed but not the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` runtime. [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.1-windows-x64-asp.net-core-runtime-installer) is the link of ASP.NET Core x64 runtime Installer and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows) is the link for the main download page. After successful installation, your `dotnet --info` command output should be similar to the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! After installing and a few missing file fixes, the api is running correctly. Worth the bounty :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the cause. I have a .net core console app. I brought in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' for HostBuilder for DI purposes.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not compatible with docker console applications.

A better way is to bring in the individual needed libraries instead:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.1" />
```

No I am able to run in docker as a console app and get dependency injection and logging.

Gina